# Android logcat: getting no fatal exceptions

Tags: android, runtime-error, logcat, fatal-error, android-logcat

I am actually developing an android application (min api:15, target api: 23). My problem is, that fatal exceptions are not shown in the logcat of the android studio. I have:

- selected the right device on logcat
- verbose mode on, no filter activated

I've tested the following code

```
Object o = null;
Log.i(TAG, o.getClass().toString());
```

on two devices:

- Sony Xperia Tipo, Android version 4.03
- Huawei P8 Lite, Android version 6.00
- Emulator, Android version 6.00

And here comes the unthinkable: on the sony device, I can see fatal errors in the logcat, on the huawei device NOT. -> I don't know why. The thing is, I need the fatal errors for debugging...

Have someone have a hint for me?
Greetings!

Comment: I also tested the code on an emulator (android 6, api 23). On this emulator i'm getting fatal exceptions ...

Comment: which IDE you are using ( Eclipse/ Studio )? Are you seeing any errors?

Comment: I'm using android studio, latest version. Yes, I can see any other information (errors, warnings, infos, ...)

Comment: paste logcat details.

Comment: Check logcat level ( verbose). Restart ADB. Restart Studio

Comment: On a side note- shouldn't logs from one phone enough to debug issue? ( just saying )

Comment: I actually only want to develop on a real device (huawei) because I need gps locations ...

Comment: aha is gps on in huawei?

Comment: maybe program is not reaching the point where it's supposed to throw error? try debugging

Comment: Yes, gps is on and functional, with google locations apis. But thats not the point. Everytime when the app crashes (maybe in an async task), I can not recognize where the error is coming from ...

Comment: the only response from the logcat is the following: 08-28 13:32:24.036 21696-21696/com.example.dominik.myapplication I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 21696 SIG: 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is something with the way you are writing your log. I am not sure what you have set TAG to but I would also try writing...

```
Log.i("Fatal", o.getClass().toString());
```

Then search your logcat for "Fatal" and it should bring you to your tag.

The only other thing I would say it could be is the device itself. I am able to see fatal errors on both a virtual 6.0 and on a physical device which is a Samsung. I would try to do a factory reset on the device. Just make sure you have anything saved that you need as it will wipe everything.

Comment: Maybe you are right with your assumption, I will try to reset my device...

Comment: sry Chris, it's a response to the comment of Bhunnu Baba (paste logcat details). It's a logcat dump from the sony xperia device which give me fatal exceptions in the logcat, but not the huawei...

Comment: I believe a better logcat to post would be on the device that is giving the issue. Please post that logcat.

Comment: Also, please add your code where you have the log. The more information we have the better we can answer/help you. Have you added log code elsewhere in the files and you aren't seeing any of them?

Comment: How can i access to the logcat on the device?

Comment: You have to have the device plugged in with USB Debugging Enabled from the developer options menu in your settings. After that make sure your device is selected in the first drop down of the "Android Monitor". Also make sure your app is selected in the drop down located directly to the right of the last one. You will only see the logcat active when your app is running and you have all of the above working.

Comment: Dear Chris, the problem is solved :-). I've reset the device to factory settings. Now i'm getting fatal errors, thanks for your suggestion! The log is inside a button-click function:  
    public void btnClickTest(View view) {
        Object o = null;
        Log.i(TAG, o.getClass().toString());
    }

Comment: Awesome I am glad to hear! Could you mark this answer as correct then? :)

Comment: You did! Thank you! :)